# Python 3 webscraping 403 error not fixed using Request

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've read through previous questions regarding getting a 403 error when trying to scrape pages that have security. Most suggest using 'Request' to set a User-Agent value. I've tried this on the page I want to scrape, and while it gets rid of the error messages, the script now just hangs (I've tried waiting about 10-15 seconds for the second print statement to produce any result).

Any ideas?

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print('Example: Search White Pages Smith in Frenchs Forest area:')

req = Request('https://www.whitepages.com.au/residential/results?name=Smith&location=Frenchs%20Forest', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

html = urlopen(req)

bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')

print(bs.h1)
```

Comment: Please fix build error by changing `html = urlopen(req).read()` to `html = urlopen(req)` 
On my side, I could get source code of that site by
    print(bs)
But this source code does not have h1, compare to what I get from View source of Chrome

Comment: I also get the source page, no issues. And also verify there is no `<h1>` tag within.

Comment: Thanks for that. Still does not produce a result when I run it (strange that it works for other websites though). Error message I now get looks like it might be just a timeout issue: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eg6.py", line 7, in <module>
    html = urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Users\e053220\AppData\Local\Continuum1\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout) ...[more stuff delteted]...ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host